# Cannot access variables values in jQuery

Tags: jquery

The issue I am having is I cannot access the value of the variables outside the function. I have just started to learn jQuery and I really like it, but this has had me stuck for quite a while now.

I have read other threads related to this, but those methods still do not work!

```
    $.get("/new/verify.php", { username: username, email: email },
        function(data){
            var stop_loading = '0';
            if(data == 'username')
            {
                alert('username taken');
                $('#username_taken_error').show();
                $('#username').focus();
                stop_loading = '1';
            }else if(data == 'email') {
                alert('email taken');
                $('#email_taken_error').show();
                $('#email').focus();
                stop_loading = '1';
            }else if(data == 'username|email') {
                alert('username/email taken');
                $('#username_taken_error').show();
                $('#email_taken_error').show();
                $('#username').focus();
                stop_loading = '1';     
            }
    });

    alert(stop_loading);

    if(stop_loading == '1') {
        alert('Stop loading');
        return false;   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `$.get()` performs an AJAX request which is asynchronous, so within your `$.get()` success function call another function with your `stop_loading` like following:

```
 $.get("/new/verify.php", { username: username, email: email },
        function(data){
            var stop_loading = '0';
            if(data == 'username')
            {
                alert('username taken');
                $('#username_taken_error').show();
                $('#username').focus();
                stop_loading = '1';
            }else if(data == 'email') {
                alert('email taken');
                $('#email_taken_error').show();
                $('#email').focus();
                stop_loading = '1';
            }else if(data == 'username|email') {
                alert('username/email taken');
                $('#username_taken_error').show();
                $('#email_taken_error').show();
                $('#username').focus();
                stop_loading = '1';     
            }
            // call function with stop_loading
            callAFunction(stop_loading);
    });

    // this function will be called
    // with stop_loading arugment

    function callAFunction(stop_loading){
      if(stop_loading == '1') {
        alert('Stop loading');
        return false;   
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variable in parent scope:
    var stop_loading = '0';

```
$.get("/new/verify.php", { username: username, email: email },
    function(data){

        if(data == 'username')
        {
            alert('username taken');
            $('#username_taken_error').show();
            $('#username').focus();
            stop_loading = '1';
        }else if(data == 'email') {
            alert('email taken');
            $('#email_taken_error').show();
            $('#email').focus();
            stop_loading = '1';
        }else if(data == 'username|email') {
            alert('username/email taken');
            $('#username_taken_error').show();
            $('#email_taken_error').show();
            $('#username').focus();
            stop_loading = '1';     
        }
});

alert(stop_loading);

if(stop_loading == '1') {
    alert('Stop loading');
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Yea I tried adding the variable outside of the ready function, adding it outside the get function and of course added it inside but every time I alert the value it's null.